# IE8 render bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Check out this page in Firefox or Chrome:

http://minorityrecruitonline-com.si-vs1222.com/college/Default1.aspx

Now check out the same page in IE8. I have tried everything to get them to appear the same in both browsers, but no can do.

Any ideas from any HTML gurus out there?

Comment: You might try asking this at http://doctype.com.

Comment: What is your job title? Unless "Designer" is in the OP's job title, SO is the place to ask CSS/HTML questions.

Comment: @EBGreen - that was just a suggestion, not a vote to close.

Comment: Hmm, makes me wonder what can possibly go wrong with table-based layouts.

Comment: I didn't dig through the html, but one interesting thing is the page looks fine in IE8 when you render it in IE7 mode.

Comment: @Jon B - Suggestion or not. The thing that matters is job title. If designer is in it then suggesting doctype is correct. If designer is not in it then suggesting doctype is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the td that has the "provena" add image in it - you don't have a valign attribute. Set that to valign="top" and you should be all set.

change:

```
<td width="224" height="364" style="background: url(/college/templates/College_Home/images/bg-ad-v.jpg) #ffffff no-repeat;" rowSpan="2">
```

to:

```
<td width="224" height="364" style="background: url(/college/templates/College_Home/images/bg-ad-v.jpg) #ffffff no-repeat;" rowSpan="2" valign="top">
```

I used IE8 Developer Tools to verify this works.